# Android: Speech Recognition Append Dictionary?

Tags: android, dictionary, speech-recognition

I'm using the Speech Recognizer Intent in Android. Is there a way to add your own customized  words or phrases to Android's Speech recognition 'dictionary'

Comment: Given that this question was asked back in 2011, does the answer of "It's not possible on Android" still hold?

iOS has had this feature since iOS 10 (2016) with contextualStrings, which allows the developer to provide array of phrases that should be recognized, even if they are not in the system vocabulary.

Maybe a similar construct exists on Android now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. You can only use the two language models supported.
The built in speech recognition provided by google only supports the dictation and search language models. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html and LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM or LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html says:

> You can make sure your users have the
>   best experience possible by requesting
>   the appropriate language model:
>   free_form for dictation, or web_search
>   for shorter, search-like phrases. We
>   developed the "free form" model to
>   improve dictation accuracy for the
>   voice keyboard, while the "web search"
>   model is used when users want to
>   search by voice

Answer (score 4):

Michael is correct, you cannot change the Language Model.

However, you can use "sounds like" algorithms to process the results from Android and match words it doesn't know.

See my answer here:

[speech recognition reduce possible search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778409/speech-recognition-reduce-possible-search-results/8779478#8779478)