# Grammar in Google Web Speech API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Can I improve Google speech API recognition by give him a words list (in my case the request of user is very predictable) to make recognition more accurate?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683772/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-grammar-with-the-html-5-speech-input-api

Comment: Has google added support for grammars since the question was answered?

Comment: @Deeps to some extent... take a look at this: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/context-strength . You can now provide hints to provide sentence context.

Comment: @PhillipS unless I am missing something this is additional functionality for Google Cloud Speech API, not for the Google implementation of the Web Speech API

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct answer is: **no, you can't**. =(

Answer (score 6):

I can't speak for Chrome, but in Android they are quite clear that you cannot provide a grammar. In Android speech recognition you are limited to a choice of two models: "free form" and "web search".

See [Android: Speech Recognition Append Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103467/android-speech-recognition-append-dictionary/6105264#6105264)

Answer (score 1):

For Google Cloud Speech API (Not Web Speech API) but some may find this useful:

Although currently in beta, Google has released new capability which allows you to

> include a list of phrases to act as "hints" to Cloud Speech-to-Text. Providing these hints, a technique called speech adaptation, helps Speech-to-Text API to recognize the specified phrases from your audio data."

See https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/context-strength