# Set grammar for webkit SpeechRecognition

Tags: speech-recognition

I'm trying to set grammar for chrome webkitSpeechRecognition object.

```
rec.grammars.addFromUri("grammar.grxml");
```

did not work. the browser just ignored the grammar (no error message was shown).

i read in this post: 
[Is Web Speech API Grammar exposed to developers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883609/is-web-speech-api-grammar-exposed-to-developers)
that - "Though w3c specified the grammar for web speech it is not yet implemented by the chrome".

is it true?
is there any known workaround?
when it should be supported?
is there any other good web based engines that supports grammars?

Comment: Yes, it is true. There is no need to ask another question about the same issue. You can contact google for the supposed schedule, it's unlikely they will answer you. If you need grammar recognition you might want to use other toolkits like pocketsphinx.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use a grammar with the HTML 5 speech input API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683772/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-grammar-with-the-html-5-speech-input-api)

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with the same problem. And very less documentation regarding this matter.

[This](http://www.fullstackhax.com/2017/03/16/speech-recognition-basics-grammars-jsgf/#respond) article posted around March 2017 also states it's not working in Chrome but Firefox.

And the answers in the following questions also confirm the same.

[Web Speech API Custom Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830438/web-speech-api-custom-words)

[Grammar in Google Web Speech API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433801/grammar-in-google-web-speech-api)

Comment: Can you please post a quick summary of the questions you posted? It could be that these might be deleted in the future, and then your answer is of no use to anyone who sees it.