# grammar in chrome web speech api

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am using google chrome with web speech api to do speech recognition. In the standard it is specified that it is possible to specify an SRGS grammar, but according to this [post](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2014/01/javascript/using-the-web-speech-api-to-control-a-html5-video) this functionality has not been implemented yet. I would like to know if this information is still true or how I could specify the grammar in chrome.

Comment: As the author of the post you linked to, I thought I'd add something. I have also been looking to see if there has been any movement on this but there doesn't appear to be. Chromestatus (https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5908775487668224) doesn't say much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use a grammar with the HTML 5 speech input API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683772/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-grammar-with-the-html-5-speech-input-api)