# Web Speech API: improve accuracy by a set of vocabulary

Tags: javascript, web, speech-recognition, vocabulary, webspeech-api

Can I improve the web speech api by setting some vocabulary for a specific application ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use a grammar with the HTML 5 speech input API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683772/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-grammar-with-the-html-5-speech-input-api)