# How do I get web speech api to recognise letters, postcodes and acronyms

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, voice-recognition, webspeech-api

I'm trying to get Web Speech api to recognize individual letters such as a postcode or vehicle registration e.g. MR32BDJ.

Sometimes it will work however other times it will try and create a word.

Is there way to tell speech api to only expect letters and numbers rather than words.
I've had a look at the SpeechGrammarLists however cannot find enough information to determine if this is the right approach

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use a grammar with the HTML 5 speech input API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683772/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-grammar-with-the-html-5-speech-input-api)