# Web Speech API - SpeechGrammar

Tags: webspeech-api

So I was looking through the Web Speech API documentation, and I came across this

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#speechreco-speechgrammar

Is it possible to use a SpeechGrammar object as a dictionary of words that the api understands?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use a grammar with the HTML 5 speech input API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683772/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-grammar-with-the-html-5-speech-input-api)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. That is exactly what it is for. MDN has a description of how to do recognition here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition

And a few open source examples that also make great starter code here:

https://github.com/mdn/web-speech-api