# speech recognition reduce possible search results

Tags: android, python, sl4a

I have started with Speech recognition using android, sl4a and python and so far, it works fine. 
My user is just supposed to input numbers between 0 and 9 with his voice. Is there a way to tell android to only search in those number and therefore reduce the time of recognition (and probably errors) ?

Answer (score 7):

No. You cannot change what google returns. You can only process the results.

Fortunately, you can process the results to increase the chance of a match.

For example, you could use a phonetic matching algorithm like
[Soundex](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/Soundex.html)

Using Soundex or something similar, if the recognizer hears something like "true" your code could still recognize it as the number 2.

Comment: Interesting idea. I am gonna give it a try.

Comment: How helpful are phonetic matching algorithms?

Comment: Phonetic matching algorithms are quite effective. Even SoundEx, which is very very simple and was originally developed for names, helps you to match. The better you tweak it the less false detections you will have.